# What is the "Secret ID" in the "Certificates & secrets" blade of Azure AD App registration and how can we use this?

Tags: azure-app-registration

What is the "Secret ID" in the "Certificates & secrets" blade of Azure AD App registration and how can we use this?

I have checked MS docs but there is no direct explanation.

Comment: My understanding is that this is an identifier that Microsoft is using to distinguish between secrets belonging to an app registration. However, I do not have any documentation to support this.

Comment: In terms of *using* a client secret have you looked at this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#add-a-client-secret

Comment: yes I checked the link and I could not find any specific definition to figure this out

Comment: secret_id - The ID of the associated Key Vault Secret- i found in terraform registry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watching the network traffic when you go to the Clients & secrets blade you'll find your browser sends a get request to [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/myorganization/applications(appId='your-app-id-here')](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/myorganization/applications(appId=%27your-app-id-here%27)) which is the Microsoft Graph REST API. In the returned JSON payload you can see where it lists the client secrets.

[image: screenshot of response JSON]

Lets see if we can find where Microsoft describes these properties - specifically keyId in this case.

According to the [Microsoft Graph REST API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) this endpoint returns the "properties and relationships of an application object". Sure enough, when we go to the [application object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0) it lists the passwordCredentials property we saw in our JSON. If we look at the [properties of passwordCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/passwordcredential?view=graph-rest-1.0) it describes keyId as: "The unique identifier for the password."
[image: Screenshot of documentation]

The purpose of this key is to identify the secret when using the [removePassword method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-removepassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). When you post to `/applications/{id}/removePassword` you must provide a keyId to identify which password you want to remove.